# How can we achieve Conditional increment in XSLT

Tags: xslt

Input:

```
<Order>
  <HeaderValue1>ORDER1</HeaderValue1>
  <OrderLineItems>
    <Item>`A`</Item>
  </OrderLineitems>
  <OrderLineItems>
    <Item>A</Item>
  </OrderLineItems>
  <OrderLineItems>
    <Item>`A`</Item>`
  </OrderLineItems>
  <OrderLineItems>`
    <Item>B</Item>`
  </OrderLineItems>
</Order>
<Order>
  <HeaderValue1>`ORDER2`</HeaderValue1>
  <OrderLineItems>
    <Item>B`</Item>
  </OrderLineItems>
</Order>
```

for each order there is a number of orderLineItems are present.For each order and items we need to assign a increment value.if the previous item value  is equal to current item value.there is no need to increment just pass the value.otherwise increment value is assign to item element.
I need the output is like below.

```
<Order>
  <HeaderValue1>1`</HeaderValue1>
  <OrderLineItems>`
    <Item>2`</Item>
  </OrderLineItems>
  <OrderLineItems>
    <Item>A`</Item>
  </OrderLineItems>
  <OrderLineItems>
    <Item>A`</Item>
  </OrderLineItems>
  <OrderLineItems>
    <Item>3`</Item>
  </OrderLineItems>
</Order>
<Order>
  <HeaderValue1>4</HeaderValue1>
  <OrderLineItems>
    <Item>5</Item>
  </OrderLineItems>
</Order>
```

Comment: The provided output seems nonsensical - even with your description, I don't understand how you get from input to output.

Comment: Could you add some detail to your question about specifically what you've tried (with code snippets), and what problems you're running into? For example, is that the output you're getting, or that you want to get?

Comment: Why have the values in the input been _replaced_ with numbers rather than having the numbers added somewhere (like in an attribute)?  Are the actual values not needed?

Comment: if the previous item is not equal to current item .there is iteration value should come for each item.

Comment: Here is the points we should consider:
1)There is number of orders are present.
2)for each order there is number of orderLineitems are there.
3)we have to assign a sequence number to each iteration but there is  a condition is present like(Conditional increment)

if the previous item value is equal to current item value.no need to increase sequence number just pass the item value.if it is not equal just increase sequence number and assign to item.

Answer (score 0):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:param name="pNum" select="0"/>
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[1]|@*">
     <xsl:with-param name="pNum" select="$pNum"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]">
   <xsl:with-param name="pNum" select="$pNum"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="HeaderValue1">
  <xsl:param name="pNum" select="0"/>

        <HeaderValue1><xsl:value-of select="$pNum+1"/></HeaderValue1>

      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]">
       <xsl:with-param name="pNum" select="$pNum+1"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="OrderLineItems[not(. = preceding-sibling::*[1])]">
  <xsl:param name="pNum" select="0"/>

        <OrderLineItems>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[1]|@*">
         <xsl:with-param name="pNum" select="$pNum+1"/>
       </xsl:apply-templates>
        </OrderLineItems>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]">
       <xsl:with-param name="pNum" select="$pNum+1"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Item[not(. = ../preceding-sibling::*[1])]">
  <xsl:param name="pNum" select="0"/>

  <Item><xsl:value-of select="$pNum"/></Item>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Order">
  <xsl:param name="pNum" select="0"/>

  <Order>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[1]|@*">
     <xsl:with-param name="pNum" select="$pNum"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]">
       <xsl:with-param name="pNum" select=
       "$pNum +1 + count(OrderLineItems[not(. = preceding-sibling::*[1])])"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
  </Order>

 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document (corrected to be well-formed):**

```
<t>
    <Order>
        <HeaderValue1>ORDER1</HeaderValue1>
        <OrderLineItems>
            <Item>A</Item>
        </OrderLineItems>
        <OrderLineItems>
            <Item>A</Item>
        </OrderLineItems>
        <OrderLineItems>
            <Item>A</Item>
        </OrderLineItems>
        <OrderLineItems>
            <Item>B</Item>
        </OrderLineItems>
    </Order>
    <Order>
        <HeaderValue1>ORDER2</HeaderValue1>
        <OrderLineItems>
            <Item>B</Item>
        </OrderLineItems>
    </Order>
</t>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<t>
   <Order>
      <HeaderValue1>1</HeaderValue1>
      <OrderLineItems>
         <Item>2</Item>
      </OrderLineItems>
      <OrderLineItems>
         <Item>A</Item>
      </OrderLineItems>
      <OrderLineItems>
         <Item>A</Item>
      </OrderLineItems>
      <OrderLineItems>
         <Item>3</Item>
      </OrderLineItems>
      <Order>
         <HeaderValue1>4</HeaderValue1>
         <OrderLineItems>
            <Item>5</Item>
         </OrderLineItems>
      </Order>
   </Order>
</t>
```