# How can we perform Conditional Increment in xslt

Tags: xslt

In a Shipment the number of orders is present. For each order there is a number of order line Items. Order Line Items contain item. For each iteration we are maintaining the hierarchy levels. In the orderLine Items section, if the previous item is equal to current item, there is no need to increment hierarchy.

points:

1. There is only one shipment
2. Number of orders are present per shipment.
3. number of  orderLineItems per each order.
4. for each iteration of orders and orderlineItems we have to maintain a hierarchy levels(increment value),but when comes to orderLineItems one condition is there if the previous item is equals to Current item,no need to increment hierarchy level.otherwise we should increment the hierarchy levels like below output we needed.

   below is the input.
   Input:

---

```
        <shipment>
 <order><!-- unbounded -->
  <value>value 4</value>
  <other>item1</other>
 <OrderLineItems><!-- unbounded -->(conditions comes under this section only not in Order section)
         <Lineitem>3</LineItem>
</OrderLineItems>
<OrderLineItems>
         <Lineitem>3</LineItem>
</OrderLineItems>
<OrderLineItems>
         <Lineitem>2</LineItem>
</OrderLineItems>        
         </order>

 <order>
  <value>value 98</value>
  <other>item2</other>
 <OrderLineItems>
         <Lineitem>8</LineItem>
</OrderLineItems>
<OrderLineItems>
         <Lineitem>3</LineItem>
</OrderLineItems>
<OrderLineItems>
         <Lineitem>4</LineItem>
</OrderLineItems>
 </order>

  <order>
  <value>value 98</value>
  <other>item2</other>
  <OrderLineItems>
         <Lineitem>8</LineItem>
</OrderLineItems>
<OrderLineItems>
         <Lineitem>3</LineItem>
</OrderLineItems>
<OrderLineItems>
         <Lineitem>4</LineItem>
</OrderLineItems>
 </order>
</shipment>
```

below is the output we need.

Output:

```
<ns1:Shipment>
   <ns1:Shipment1>1</ns1:Shipment1>
   <ns1:ShipmentValue>S</ns1:ShipmentValue>
   <ns1:Order>
      <ns1:Orderlevel1>2</ns1:Orderlevel1>
      <ns1:Orderlevel2>1</ns1:Orderlevel2>
      <ns1:Orderlevel3>O</ns1:Orderlevel3>
      <ns1:OrderLineItems>
         <ns1:Level1>3</ns1:Level1>
         <ns1:Level2>2</ns1:Level2>
         <ns1:Level3>I</ns1:Level3>
         <ns1:Item>Item59</ns1:Item>
      </ns1:OrderLineItems>
      <ns1:OrderLineItems>
         <ns1:Item>Item59</ns1:Item>
      </ns1:OrderLineItems>
       <ns1:OrderLineItems>
        <ns1:Level1>4</ns1:Level1>
         <ns1:Level2>2</ns1:Level2>
         <ns1:Level3>I</ns1:Level3>
         <ns1:Item>Item63</ns1:Item>
      </ns1:OrderLineItems>
   </ns1:Order>
   <ns1:Order>
      <ns1:Orderlevel1>5</ns1:Orderlevel1>
      <ns1:Orderlevel2>1</ns1:Orderlevel2>
      <ns1:Orderlevel3>O</ns1:Orderlevel3>
      <ns1:OrderLineItems>
         <ns1:Level1>6</ns1:Level1>
         <ns1:Level2>5</ns1:Level2>
         <ns1:Level3>I</ns1:Level3>
         <Item>Item74</Item>
      </ns1:OrderLineItems>
       <ns1:OrderLineItems>
       <ns1:Level1>7</ns1:Level1>
         <ns1:Level2>5</ns1:Level2>
         <ns1:Level3>I</ns1:Level3>
        <Item>Item78</Item>
      </ns1:OrderLineItems>   
      <ns1:OrderLineItems>
         <ns1:Item>Item78</ns1:Item>
      </ns1:OrderLineItems>
 </ns1:Order>
</ns1:Shipment>
```

---

Comment: Could you clarify your question and use smaller examples. Maybe even create a minimal example of what it is you want to achieve?

Comment: From the input we are getting Shipment data.There is number of orders per shipment.per each order there is multiple orderLineItems.The Order and OrderLineitems should iterate.for each iteration we should maintain a hierarchy levels,but here one condition is there ,if the previous item value is equal to current item value,no need to increment the hierarchy level value .otherwise we need to increment the hierarchy of order and orderlineItems depends on how many times it iterate.

Comment: Why are the "Level3" elements being set to contain either "O" or "I"?

Comment: In my requirement for the Order hierarchy the Level3 element is 'O' and and for the Item Hierarchy the level3 element is 'I'. no problem with this we can hard code this 'O' and 'I'

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can we achieve Conditional increment in XSLT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15418585/how-can-we-achieve-conditional-increment-in-xslt)

Comment: This is the exact requirement and is quite differrent from old.How can we get the Level2 element also some number which is shown above.

Comment: can we get this logic in a single template(Not using more templates).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've simplified your problem (assuming I understand it correctly, which I'm not sure of).

Anyway, for this XML:

```
<shipment>
 <order>
  <value>value 4</value>
  <other>item1</other>
 </order>
 <order>
  <value>value 98</value>
  <other>item2</other>
 </order>
 <order>
  <value>value 98</value>
  <other>item3</other>
 </order>
 <order>
  <value>another value</value>
  <other>item4</other>
 </order>
</shipment>
```

I'm getting the following output (note `<counter>` elements which are incrementing each time `<value>` is changing):

```
<shipment>
   <order>
      <counter>1</counter>
      <value>value 4</value>
      <other>item1</other>
   </order>
   <order>
      <!-- counter incremented, because value changed
           from "value 4" to "value 98" -->
      <counter>2</counter>
      <value>value 98</value>
      <other>item2</other>
   </order>
   <order>
      <!-- counter not incremented, value still "value 98" -->
      <counter>2</counter>
      <value>value 98</value>
      <other>item3</other>
   </order>
   <order>
      <!-- counter incremented, because value changed
           from "value 98" to "another value" -->
      <counter>3</counter>
      <value>another value</value>
      <other>item4</other>
   </order>
</shipment>
```

If that's something what is useful to you, have a look at this stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/">
  <shipment>
    <!-- call template for first <order> only. All subsequent <order>
         elements will be called recursively by this template itself -->
    <xsl:call-template name="order">
      <xsl:with-param name="prevValue" select="string('')"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="counter" select="0"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="self" select="/shipment/order[1]"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </shipment>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="order">
  <xsl:param name="prevValue"/>
  <xsl:param name="counter"/>
  <xsl:param name="self"/>

  <xsl:variable name="selfCounter">
    <xsl:choose>
      <!-- if the <value> is the same as in previous <order>, 
           do not increment <counter> -->
      <xsl:when test="$prevValue = $self/value">
        <xsl:value-of select="$counter"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <!-- if the value is different, increment <counter> by one -->
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$counter + 1"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:variable>

  <order>
    <!-- copy all the original children of <order>,
         and add <counter> -->
    <counter><xsl:value-of select="$selfCounter"/></counter>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$self/node()" />
  </order>

  <!-- if there is another <order>, call this template -->
  <xsl:if test="$self/following-sibling::order[1]">
        <xsl:call-template name="order">
          <xsl:with-param name="prevValue" select="$self/value"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="counter" select="$selfCounter"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="self" select="$self/following-sibling::order[1]"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I have added the input xml can u please specify the counter variable for this structure.